# Write this in matrix form?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to work on my linear algebra skills. I came across this equation in Bishop PRML (Equation 4.93):

$$ \nabla E(w) = \sum_{n=1}^N(\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{\phi}_n-t_n)\mathbf{\phi}_n = \mathbf{\Phi}^T\mathbf{\Phi w} - \mathbf{\Phi^T t}$$

Where $\mathbf{w, \phi_n, t}$ are vectors and $\mathbf{\Phi}$ is a $N$ by $M$ matrix whose $n^{th}$ row is given by $\mathbf{\phi}_n^T$.

The matrix form confuses me. I understand how he derives the $\mathbf{\Phi ^Tt}$ part, but really can't figure out how he came up with $\mathbf{\Phi^T\Phi w}$

I hope one of you can explain it to me :)

Thanks

P.S. Tips on how to structurally figure these matrix forms out in general are really appreciated.

Comment: Hmm this seems a little fishy, perhaps there's a typo and the first term should be $\Phi\Phi^T$ or the second term should be $\Phi^T$? In the first case consider $\Phi$ to be the matrix with $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n$ as its column vectors and in the second case consider $\Phi$ to be the matrix with $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n$ as its row vectors.

Comment: Excuse me, the second term should've had a $\Phi^T$.  Fixed that now. However, the first term still confuses me. It's equation 4.93 in Bishop's PRML, by the way.

Comment: If you want to build intuition, try computing the following terms: given an arbitrary $x,y$ of the correct dimensions what is $\Phi x$ and what is $\Phi^T y$? To relate it back to the problem note that the quantity you're interested in can be written as $\Phi^T(\Phi w - t)$, then take $x = w$ and $y = \Phi x - t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{equation}
 \Phi 
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \phi_1^T \\ \vdots \\ \phi_N^T
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 \Phi w
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \phi_1^T \\ \vdots \\ \phi_N^T
 \end{bmatrix}
 w
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \phi_1^T w\\ \vdots \\ \phi_N^Tw
 \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
 \Phi^T\Phi w
 =
\underbrace{
 \begin{bmatrix}
  \phi_1 & \ldots & \phi_N
 \end{bmatrix}}_{\Phi^T} 
\underbrace{
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \phi_1^T w\\ \vdots \\ \phi_N^Tw
 \end{bmatrix}}_{\Phi w} 
 =
 \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \phi_n (\phi_n^T w) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Also
\begin{equation}
 \Phi^T t
 =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \phi_1 & \ldots & \phi_N
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  t_1 \\
  \vdots \\
  t_N
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \sum\limits_{n=1}^N
 t_n \phi_n\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get
\begin{equation}
 \Phi^T\Phi w-\Phi^T t
 =
  \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \phi_n (\phi_n^T w)
  -
  \sum\limits_{n=1}^N
 t_n \phi_n
 =
 \sum\limits_{n=1}^N\phi_n (\phi_n^T w) - t_n\phi_n
\end{equation}
Since $(\phi_n^T w)$ and $t_n$ are scalars, we could flip
\begin{equation}
 \Phi^T\Phi w-\Phi^T t
 =
 \sum\limits_{n=1}^N (\phi_n^T w)\phi_n - t_n\phi_n
 =
 \sum\limits_{n=1}^N [(\phi_n^T w)- t_n]\phi_n 
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks Ahmad! I gave it a go myself. Could you check my reasoning? 

Since $w^T\phi_n$ are scalars, the final output of the sum will be a sum of scalars  and vectors $\phi_n$: 

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    w^T\phi_1 & \dots  & w^T\phi_N
\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf{\Phi}
$$
where the rows of $\mathbf{\Phi}$ are $\phi_n$. 

Now the first vector of vector products can be decomposed as well:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
w^T\phi_1 & \dots  & w^T\phi_N
\end{bmatrix} = w^T\mathbf{\Phi}
$$
So the final result is $w^T\mathbf{\Phi \Phi}$, right? How could I rewrite my solution to $\mathbf{\Phi^T \Phi}w$?

Comment: Excuse me, I think it should be $w^T\mathbf{\Phi}^T\mathbf{\Phi}$ which is the same as Bishop's solution, thanks!

Comment: Yes you're right @David

Answer (score 2):

Use the standard vector basis $\{e_n\}$ to express the subscripted quantities.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi_n &= \Phi^Te_n &\implies \phi_n^T = e_n^T\Phi \cr
 t_n &= e_n^Tt &\implies t = t_ne_n \cr
}$$
Recall that the identity matrix can be written in terms of the basis vectors.
$${\mathbb I}=\sum_n e_ne_n^T = e_ne_n^T$$
where the far RHS uses the Einstein summation convention, i.e. omits the explicit $\Sigma$-symbol and implicitly sums over the repeated index. It removes the visual "clutter" from the equations, so I'll use it below.

Substitute the basis vectors into your equation
$$\eqalign{
(w^T\phi_n-t_n)\phi_n
 &= \phi_n\phi_n^Tw-\phi_nt_n \cr
 &= (\Phi^Te_n)(e_n^T\Phi)\,w-(\Phi^Te_n)\,t_n \cr
 &= \Phi^T{\mathbb I}\,\Phi w-\Phi^T\,t \cr
 &= \Phi^T\Phi w-\Phi^Tt \cr
}$$